# Pass viewmodel as argument

Tags: java, android, viewmodel

Is it appropriate/accetable to reference view model as argument in other class? Is there any memory leaks?

```
LoadData(viewmodel)
```

MainFragment.java

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        
        //DataViewModel
        DataViewModel model = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(DataViewModel.class);
        
        //This is the callback method with viewmodel as argument
        new GetDataUtil().LoadData(model);
      
        model.getListData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), item -> item.getNote()); //UI update work in progress
        return view;
    }
}
```

GetDataUtil.java

```
public class GetDataUtil {
    List<Note> listData = new ArrayList<>();

    //Asynchronous method to load data from internet, in this case firestore
    //This is what I mean when using viewmodel as parameter
    public void LoadData(DataViewModel model){

        //Asynchronous task start block {                
                listData.add(Note); //For loop add data from querysnapshot
                model.getListData().setValue(listData);
        //Asynchronous task end block }
    }
}
```

DataViewModel.java

```
public class DataViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<List<Note>> listData = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public MutableLiveData<List<Note>> getListData(){
        return listData;
    }
}
```

I'm still beginner in android development, it would be better if someone show me related article or documentation regarding rules using viewmodel, [this](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-and-livedata-patterns-antipatterns-21efaef74a54) is what I am trying to understand. Thanks

Comment: Instead of having your activity ask for data from `GetDataUtil`, it'd be better to have `ViewModel` do it. Create an instance of `GetDataUtil` in the `ViewModel` and let it handle it.

Comment: @Qunata Yeah I think so too, but from article I read that don't put logic in viewmodel. Is it safe?